# Using Dispatch Async in Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

Would it be better practice to have UI updates to be called on main thread with dispatch_async when I'm using a block for example:

```
    PFFile *image = (PFFile *)[currentUser objectForKey:@"image"];
    [image getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error){
        if (error)
        {
            self.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];

        }
        else
        {
            UIImage *userImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            self.profileImage.image = userImage;
        }
    }];
```

Would it be better if I put "self.profileImage.image = userImage;" in a dispatch async within that else conditional or does it matter since its a block and is called async as is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform image loading operation in main thread.

`self.profileImage.image = userImage;`

Above line is UI operation and as it is in a block, It will take some time to load and make your UI interaction stop for a bit of time.

You just need to call this line in a main thread:

```
PFFile *image = (PFFile *)[currentUser objectForKey:@"image"];
[image getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error){
    if (error)
    {
        self.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];

    }
    else
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadImage:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

    }
}];


- (void) loadImage:(NSData *)data {
            UIImage *userImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            self.profileImage.image = userImage;
}
```

Comment: UIImage operations are not UI operations. UIImageView operations are, however, and should be performed on the main thread.

Comment: @jshier:Agreed, I forgot to mention that part. Edited answer

Answer (score 0):

If setting `self.profileImage.image` results in an immediate change in the UI that you want the user to see, then you should set that property on the main queue. If you're just setting internal data that's not immediately relevant to the UI then you can continue to perform it on a background queue. So if you wanted to update the profile image on the main queue, you would use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    self.profileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

Comment: Any reason I would be getting this " A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
" from that now? seems to be happening now.

Comment: This means you've locked up the main thread of your application, possibly through some form of [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).